# C++ comparing two numbers by their digits

Tags: c++, numbers, compare, digits

I want to make a function, which returns true whenever two numbers provided on input are made up of the same digits (with no replacement).

For example, 543 and 435 should return true, 10001 and 11000 should return true, but 111222 and 122222 should return false.

I've read something about bitmasks but do not really get it, could You help me?

Comment: You could count how many times each digit appears in the numbers, or you could try sorting the digits and then comparing the values.

Comment: If you use `x % 10` it gives you the bottom digit. If you use `x / 10` it removes the bottom digit. You can then count or sort the digits in each number and compare.

Comment: Convert the numbers to std::string and use std::map<char,int> or just an  int array[10];

Comment: "_I've read something about bitmasks but do not really get it_" This is not the use case for bitmasks. They are used for entirely different purpose. What did you attempt? One could split the number to digits, put them to `std::map`, and then compare the maps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not attempt was made to solve the problem. So short of writting the answer which does not help future user we can't do more than comment.

Comment: Alright, I already have an idea how to accomplish it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think to handle this is to use buckets. Create an `std::vector` of length 10 (one for each digit) and then increment an index whenever you run across the corresponding digit. Finish by comparing vectors:

```
bool compare_digits(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<int> x_vec(10), y_vec(10);
    while(x != 0) { //!= instead of > so that we can handle negatives
        x_vec.at(x%10)++; //increment whatever digit is in the 1's place
        x /= 10; //chop off the 1's place digit
    }

    while(y != 0) { //repeat for y
        y_vec.at(y%10)++;
        y /= 10;
    }

    //check if they had the same digits
    return (x_vec == y_vec);
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to use bound checking for modulos operation. And if you do not want to create separate function just use lambda, code repetition is source of problems.

Comment: @Slava I assume when you talk about bounds checking, you're referencing my use of `.at()` over the subscript operator? I don't think it would really impact the run-time here and it's probably a good habit for a budding C++ programmer, so I don't think I'll change it. What are you saying I should lambda?

Comment: " it's probably a good habit" I do not think so, it conflicts with one of the main principle of C++ "I should not pay for what I do not use". And for lambda I mean duplicate code of converting `int` to vector

Comment: @Slava it's insurance. You may use it, you may not. And you're not going to know whether or not you need to use it until you really need it. And by then it's too late. I'd prefer to make all of my subscripts `.at()`'s for an itty bitty price to runtime for that one time it saves me 5 hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Two numbers a made up of the same digits, if the counts (number of occurrences) of each digit are the same. Here is some code for a general base (template parameter)

```
template<int base=10>
bool compare_digits(int x, int y)
{
    // 0 exclude trivial cases
    if(x > base*y || y > base*x)
        return false;
    // 1 count occurrences of digits in x
    int count[base]={0};
    for(; x; x/=base)
        ++ count[x%base];
    // 2 subtract counts of digits in y, if result < 0: return false
    for(; y; y/=base)
        if(--count[y%base] < 0)
            return false;
    // 3 check that count[]==0
    for(int i=0; i!=base; ++i)
        if(count[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```